# Proving that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is not isomorphic as a ring to $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^2)$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

How do I prove that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^2)$ are not isomorphic as rings? It is easy to show that they are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras; but an arbitrary ring homomorphism could send an element of $\mathbb{R}^*$ to some other invertible element. The usual properties do not distinguish the two rings (reducedness, dimension, normality, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_1=\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ is four-dimensional with $\Bbb R$-basis $1$, $x$, $y$, $xy$.

$R_2=\Bbb R[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^2)$ is four-dimensional with $\Bbb R$-basis $1$, $x$, $y$, $x^2$.

Both are local rings: the maximal ideal of $R_1$ is $M_1=(x,y)$ and the
maximal ideal of $R_2$ is $M_2=(x,y)$. A homomorphism $\phi:R_1\to R_2$
must take $M_1$ to $M_2$. Therefore $\phi(x)=ax+by+cx^2$
where $a$, $b$, $c\in\Bbb R$. As $x^2=0$ in $R_1$ then $(ax+by+cx^2)^2=0$ in $R_2$.
But
$$(ax+by+cx^2)^2=a^2x^2+2abxy+b^2y^2=(a^2+b^2)x^2$$
in $R_2$ and so $a^2+b^2=0$, that is $a=b=0$, and so $\phi(x)=cx^2$.
Likewise $\phi(y)=dy^2$ where $d\in \Bbb R$. Some  non-trivial
$\Bbb R$-linear combination of $x$ and $y$ must be sent to zero by $\phi$.
Therefore $\phi$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Why is $c$ zero?

Comment: This is exactly what I did, but I think this only shows that $\phi$ cannot be an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism. The second to last sentence is not true for an arbitrary ring-homomorphism.

Comment: @Jehu314 I don't think that this is problematic. Use that $\phi$ induces an isomorphism of graded rings $R_1/M_1\oplus M_1/M_1^2\oplus M_1^2\to R_2/M_2\oplus M_2/M_2^2\oplus M_2^2$. In degree zero, this is an isomorphism $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ which must be the identity, so the graded ring homomorphism is $\Bbb R$-linear. Then the same argument applies.

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks!